# Output utf-8 to console

Tags: c, windows, encoding, stdout

I have this code to print an utf-8 char to windows console:

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
freopen(NULL, "w,ccs=UTF-8", stdout);

wchar_t u16 = 0x00A9;
unsigned char utf8_b[] = {0xc2, 0xa9, 0x0}; //same as using WideCharToMultibyte for u16
printf("%s", utf8_b); //(1)
wprintf(L"%c", u16); //(2)
```

(1) produces correct output which is '©', while (2)'s output is the replacement character  U+FFFD. I tried redirecting stdout (2) to a file to see if there's a problem with encoding conversion but it products the same byte sequences as utf8_b[].

Can anyone explain to me why is that ? Is this a windows problem ?

btw, my console font is already set to Consolas.

edit: I comment (1) before using (2), so I think it doesn't related to stream orientation here.
I've read somewhere that some implementation bugs in windows code page 65001 can affect C standard IO. Can anyone confirm this for me ?

Comment: What about [`putwchar`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/putwchar/)?

Comment: @Kninnug same result as (2) =.=

Comment: This doesn't repro at all for me.  What version of VS is this?

Answer (score 0):

Mixing wide and byte oriented output on the same FILE stream invokes undefined behavior. You should try instead using `printf("%lc", u16);` or eliminating all byte-oriented output.